# Any documentation for Nvidia's Monitor 'API'?

Tags: nvidia

I'm looking for a way to control which monitors are currently being used via my desktop from a program.   Well after a quick search I seen on Nvidia's site that their API will allow you to control the monitors... GREAT!   Too bad I'm having a pretty hard time finding anything more about this... searching Nvidia's site with multiple phrases does not help nor did google off hand.

So if anyone knows of any material on the subject it would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!
(Still looking myself too)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look under the Developer Zone.  All the specifications and SDKs are there.